# Como inserir um valor de uma ViewBag em um Elemento HTML via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Preciso passa um valor de uma viewbag para um elemento HTML via javascript, e não sei a sintaxe correta para fazê-lo... Bom, poderia passar esse valor da forma tradicional, mas preciso setar esse valor via javascript...
Exemplo(desta forma não dá certo):

```html
script>
    function pegavalor() {
        document.getElementById('CategoriaDescricao').value = @ViewBag.CategoriaDescricao;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Já tentou trocar para o `.value` para `.innerHTML` ?? Como essa function será acionada? Após clicar em um botão.. ou quando a página carregar..

Comment: será acionada por um botão... mas até aí blz.... mas o o meu maior problema é que não consigo trabalhar com uma Viewbag dentro da function javascript.... EX:
var categoriaid = @ViewBag.CategoriaID;

isso não funciona :(